# Matching time series using Support Vector Machines (SVM)

Tags: graph, machine-learning, pattern-matching, svm

Given two different graphs, can I use SVM to detect whether they are closely (not exactly) matching with a defined margin of error or threshold? If yes, what are the steps? How do I do it? Sorry I am very new to the field of machine learning and appreciate expertise help.

Reason I am asking is that I have a set of (x) inputs over (t) time that I would like to verify and match against predefined sets of (x) values over (t). This can be used in motion type detection using accelerometers on mobile devices.

Comment: I read "graph matching" to be *Graph Matching*(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29), you may want to change your title to be more like "Matching time series using support vector machines"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the the first sentences of your two paragraphs: you just want to detect when a new
instance is "close to" any one of the instances in your predefined set of time-series.
The straightforward way to do that is to just do it; no need for fancy machine learning algorithms.

If you don't want to compare each instance against everything in you predefined set,
then you could (possibly) try to distil it down to a fewer number prototypes, using a clustering or other unsupervised learning algorithm.

The SVM is typically used to solve data-driven *classification* problems where you have:
two (or more) labelled data sets, each with many instances; each instance has a set of feature values, and you want to construct a classification model that will label subsequent data.

Comment: Actually I think in my case SVM is more appropriate. What I intend to do is collect a set of training data, each of which can be labelled specifically. In the case of accelerometer motion type detection, I will have 10 samplings for running, 10 samplings for jumping and etc. Then I want to use those samples to train the system. At runtime, I would like to feed the system with dynamically collected samples and label them accordingly. It's a bit similar to hand-writing recognition, except that instead of handwriting images, I have graphs of movements over time.

Comment: Now I am confused on how to convert my data into inputs acceptable by SVM. For example in case of handwriting, how do they convert images into something that svm can process. Sorry I might sound very stupid, but I am very new to machine learning and I have very little time for implementation of the mentioned project.

Comment: You should add these additional details into your question.

Comment: In my opinion, feature selection, i.e. how to map the raw data into the data format required by the machine learning algorithm is exactly the key step in the whole process.